# Data Structure to represent a DAG in Javascript

Tags: javascript, graph, directed-acyclic-graphs

I have a string that I need to parse into a graph (DAG) data structure using javascript.  Included in the data structure are a few attributes I should store, such as the node's id, name, and a label that is given to the link if one exists to another node.  So, an example would be

```
Node1 (id: 1, name: 'first') --('link name')--> Node2 (id:....)
```

and so forth.  Once the data structure is created I do not need to do any more operations on it other than read it (I will later use it to render a visualization with d3).  The amount of nodes will not be very many, as several of them are shared.

I am imagining an adjacency list but am not sure how I would encode that in javascript.  For instance, I know a json object can have a "field" : "value" structure but can I do that with Object : [list of adjacent Objects]?

Comment: [https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/tree/master/packages/ember-application/lib/system/dag.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/62e52938f48278a6cb838016108f3e35c18c8b3f/packages/ember-application/lib/system/dag.js)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use lists (arrays) in json.  E.g. I could represent a simple directed graph as

```
{
  "NodeA": {"name": "NodeA", "adjacentTo": ["NodeB", "NodeC"]},
  "NodeB": {"name": "NodeB", "adjacentTo": ["NodeC", "NodeD"]},
  "NodeC": {"name": "NodeC", "adjacentTo": ["NodeA"]},
  "NodeD": {"name": "NodeD", "adjacentTo": []}
}
```

This would be the graph:

```
C
^^
| \
|  \
A -> B -> D
```

The name field really isn't needed, but you can associate any attributes you want with a node that way.

Comment: I see.  I ended up doing something like adjList = ["id" : "1", "name" : "A", "adjacentTo" : ["2", "3"], "adjacentToLink" : ["link_for_2", "link_for_3"]].  So, just lists within the list as you demonstrated.  Thanks, it really cleared up my head.

Comment: Is NodeC really adjacent to NodeA?

Comment: NodeC is not adjacent to NodeA, like NodeD is not adjacent to NodeB either, they're both leaves.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript objects must have string keys, but can store any type of value. Of course, the entire point in an id is to allow you to represent a complex type wirh a simple one.

```
var adjacentTo = {};
adjacentTo[node1.id] = [node2, node3]
```