# What method could be used for a traversable tree with dependencies within JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, algorithm, tree

Possibly the worst title ever since I wasn't sure how to phrase it, but hopefully I can explain better here. Please note that wrong terminology will be abound in this question and I apologise for it.

I would like to try and build a JS application in node that can traverse a dependency tree. Usually a normal tree traversed with jQuery would be fine, but I think this is a little more complicated than that.

I have this image as an example:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U9lso.png (Updated from previous image as in some browsers it redirected to a smaller resolution)

I would like to be able to pick a node and have the application output the most efficient route to that node including all dependencies. For example, if I wanted to get to Shielding Technology 1, it would output:
Research Lab 1 -> Research lab 2 -> Research lab 3 -> Research lab 4 -> Research lab 5 -> Research lab 6 -> Energy Technology 1 -> Energy Technology 2 -> Energy Technology 3 -> Shielding Technology 1

In this example, research labs are the priority, but any order would be fine as long as it followed both paths.

So far I haven't really got a clue how to approach it. If it were a simple tree structure without multiple dependencies I would just set it up as a tree.

Please feel free to extract smaller examples if you have an idea of how to do it.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's a large resolution, you may need to click to zoom or ctrl+scrollwheel.

Comment: It's very low res (200 * 43 pixels)

Comment: it depends on the browser, on ie11 there is nothing to see, in ff (version, don't know) there is a readable diagram.

Comment: @NinaScholz Try the updated image for me? The original image still links to a 3599x764 image for me (Chrome) and this new one should also.

Comment: [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646560/data-structure-to-represent-a-dag-in-javascript) might be helpful.  If I'm getting the question right, you're trying to create a [directed graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) and find the [shortest possible path to one of the nodes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm).  The first link I posted describes how you could create an adjacency matrix in JSON to accomplish the first bit.

Comment: @alex You're right, I am pretty much trying to create a directed graph, but I'm not necessarily trying to find the shortest path possible as I need it to include certain pre-requisites. If A and B are parent nodes, and C is a child node to both, I need to travel through both A and B before reaching C.

Comment: @ConnorBell Can you elaborate a little bit on the parent nodes thing?  Are you trying to find all paths that end in C?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd definitely recommend doing some research about directed graphs as [candu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2113342/candu) suggested and finding a way to accomplish this that you're comfortable with.  There's probably a lot of different ways you could go about doing this, and it's up to you to figure out the preferred architecture.

If you're just messing around with directed graphs, I came up with my own "club-level" solution, which probably does not employ best practices, and is a little too sketchy to use in production code (unless you know what you're doing).  There's probably a few improvements that can be made to what I've written.  **Caveat emptor!**

First, I created an array to represent each of the individual nodes in the directed acyclic graph (or "DAG"), and gave each of them a unique ID.  The ID corresponds to its position in the `nodes` array.

```
var nodes = [];

nodes.push(
    {
        Name: "Research Lab 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Research Lab 2",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Computer Technology 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Energy Technology 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Combustion Drive 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Energy Technology 2",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Computer Technology 8",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Impulse Drive 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Research Lab 3",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    },
    {
        Name: "Armor Technology 1",
        Adjacencies: [],
        ID: null
    });

for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodes[i]["ID"] = i;
}
```

---

Once the nodes are enumerated, the parent/child (or tail/head) relationships between the nodes must be established.  I used the term 'adjacency' to refer to a parent/child relationship between two nodes.<sup>1</sup>

First, I created a function that would populate a node object's `Adjacencies` property - which will eventually be used to create an adjacency matrix based off of the `nodes` array.

```
Array.prototype.addAdjacency = function (tail, head) {
    var thisNode = findNode(tail);
    thisNode["Adjacencies"].push(findNode(head).Name);
}

// This will return the node object with a given name:
function findNode(name) {
    return $.grep(nodes, function (n) {
        return n.Name == name
    })[0];
}
```

Finally, we can manually specify each node's tail/head relationships.

```
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 1", "Research Lab 2");
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 1", "Computer Technology 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 1", "Energy Technology 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 2", "Impulse Drive 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 2", "Research Lab 3");
nodes.addAdjacency("Research Lab 2", "Armor Technology 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Computer Technology 1", "Computer Technology 8");
nodes.addAdjacency("Computer Technology 1", "Impulse Drive 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Energy Technology 1", "Combustion Drive 1");
nodes.addAdjacency("Energy Technology 1", "Energy Technology 2");
nodes.addAdjacency("Energy Technology 1", "Impulse Drive 1");
```

---

The [adjacency matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix) is a two-dimensional array that shows you every tail/head relationship between each node in the DAG - sort of an added convenience.  In my implementation, if `adjacencyMatrix[0][3] === true`, then `nodes[0]` is a parent of `nodes[3]` (in other words, "Research Lab 1" is a parent of "Energy Technology 1").

```
function isAdjacent(tail, head) {
    return tail["Adjacencies"].indexOf(head.Name) != -1;
}

var adjacencyMatrix = populateAdjacencyMatrix(nodes);

function populateAdjacencyMatrix(vertices) {

    var matrix = new Array(vertices.length);

    for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
        matrix[i] = new Array(vertices.length);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < matrix.length; j++) {
            if (isAdjacent(vertices[i], vertices[j])) {
                matrix[i][j] = true;
            } else {
                matrix[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

---

Once the adjacency matrix is complete, we can recursively traverse through the matrix to find each of the paths leading to a given node.

```
var pathsToNode = [];

// ... e.g. the node at index 7, or "Impulse Drive 1":
findPathTo(nodes[7], []);

function findPathTo(node, path) {
    var nodeID = node["ID"];
    var parentNodeIndices = [];
    var currentNodeIsRootNode = true;

    // A new array based off of the path argument needs to be created, or else things get a little wacky with the scope.
    var currentPath = new Array();

    for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
        currentPath.push(path[i]);
    }

    // Next, add the node in this context to the 'current path'.
    currentPath.unshift(nodeID);

    // Note that if there are no paths leading up to this node, then it's the first node in the directed path.
    for (var i = 0; i < adjacencyMatrix[0].length; i++) {
        var matrixValue = adjacencyMatrix[i][nodeID];
        if (matrixValue === true) {
            currentNodeIsRootNode = false;
            parentNodeIndices.push(i);
        }
    }

    // Finally, if the node in /this/ recursive context is a "root" node (i.e. it has no parents),
    // then add the entire path to the list of paths to the original node.
    if (currentNodeIsRootNode) {
        //console.log(" ");
        //console.log("Adding path to paths array:")
        //console.log(currentPath);
        //console.log("This is now what the paths array looks like:")
        //console.log(pathsToNode);
        pathsToNode.push(currentPath);
    } else {
        // Otherwise, get all of the indices of the 'parent' nodes (relative to the node in this recursive context),
        // and recursively find the parent nodes of each.

        //console.log(" ");
        //console.log("Recursing findPathTo function.  Next nodes:")
        //console.log(nextNodeIndices);
        //console.log("Current path:")
        //console.log(currentPath);
        for (var i = 0; i < parentNodeIndices.length; i++) {
            findPathTo(nodes[parentNodeIndices[i]], currentPath);
        }
    }
}

console.log(pathsToNode);
```

Finally, given `nodes[7]`, we have an array of arrays called `pathsToNode` filled with the ordered node paths from a "root" node to the given node. A path like `[1, 3, 5]` means `nodes[1]` is a parent of `nodes[3]` and `nodes[3]` is a parent of `nodes[5]`.

Hope this helps, cheers! :)

<sup>1</sup><sub>This may be an incorrect usage of the term.</sub>

Comment: An amazing and in-depth answer. Candu had a great idea but your went above and beyond to answer it how I needed to understand it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3):

The dependency structure isn't a tree, it's a [directed acyclic graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph), or DAG:

- *directed*: the edges go from one node to the other, and thus have direction;
- *acyclic*: there are no cycles;
- *graph*: nodes can have more than one incoming edge (unlike *trees*, where they have at most one parent).

(I mention this because DAGs are awesome and useful in a variety of applications, including this one.  It's worth your time to learn about them.)

What you're looking for is a [depth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) traversal from your "target" node.  (In your example image, you'd be traversing backwards along the edges.)

Which one do you want?  That depends on what you want to prioritize: depth-first will tend to complete chains first (e.g. RL1 -> RL2 -> ... -> ET1 -> ET2 -> ... as in your proposed "route"), while breadth-first will tend to complete "levels" first (e.g. RL1 -> ET1 -> RL2 -> ET2 -> ...)

Comment: That sounds absolutely fantastic! I'll take a look at this and get back to with a tick, thank you!