# Modeling a prerequisite schema of courses as a tree

Tags: javascript, data-structures, tree

I'm creating a website to interact with courses and their prerequisites. 
**This is for free, isn't a homework and I'm using this project to learn MERN** 
I did this tree schema which represents all courses and their dependencies.
[image]
Notice that a **course can have more than one prerequisite**.
So I'm having rough time translating this into TDA. I have been trying with multi parents tree but I have no results due to:

- Can't recreate multiparents into one node
- Can't traverse a tree with implementations so I can't know which courses are available

I was using this Tree/Node definition in JS. I didn't try with Python but I have no problem in using another language even when I know language isn't the problem.

```js
class Tree {
    constructor(root) {
      this._root = root || null;
    }
  
     _traverse(callback) {
      const self = this;
      function goThrough(node) {
        callback(node);
        node.children.forEach((child) => {
          goThrough(child);
        });
      }
      goThrough(this._root);
    }
  
  
    _addNode(value, parentValue) {
      const newNode = {
        value,
        children: []
      };
  
      if (this._root === null) {
        this._root = newNode;
        return;
      }
  
      this._traverse((node) => {
        if (node.value === parentValue) {
          node.children.push(newNode);
        }
      });
    }
  
    _removeNode(value) {
      this._traverse((node) => {
        node.children.forEach((childNode, index) => {
          if (childNode.value === value) {
            node.children.splice(index, 1);
          }
        });
      })
    }
  
    _search(value) {
      let returnNode = 'Not Found';
      this._traverse((node) => {
        if (node.value === value) {
          returnNode = node;
        }
      });
      return returnNode;
    }
  
    _displayLeafs(parentValue) {
      const parentNode = typeof parentValue === 'string' ? this._search(parentValue) : parentValue ;
      let leafsRet = [];
      if (parentValue.children && !parentValue.children.length) {
        return parentValue;
      }
  
      parentNode.children.forEach((child) => {
        leafsRet.push(this._displayLeafs(child));
      });
  
      return leafsRet.flat();
    }
  
  }
  
  class Node {
    constructor(value, children) {
      this.value = value;
      this.children = children;
    }
  }

const malla = new Tree();

malla._addNode('root');

malla._addNode('CMB1000','root');
malla._addNode('CMB1001','root');
malla._addNode('CIT1000','root');
malla._addNode('FIC1000','root');
malla._addNode('CBQ100','root');


malla._addNode('CIT1010','CIT1000');

console.log(malla._displayLeafs('root'));
```

I didn't follow inserting new nodes because I'm not getting results as expected.  
Can anyone give a hint about a tree implemention that may I know? Or maybe a better approach to this situation?  
Thanks for your time!

Comment: *"So I'm having rough time translating this into TDA."* What's a TDA?

Comment: Perhaps the keyword "directed acyclic graph" will help you more than the keyword "tree". See for instance [Data Structure to represent a DAG in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12646560/data-structure-to-represent-a-dag-in-javascript) and [JS library for displaying direct acyclic graphs (DAGs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16647456/js-library-for-displaying-direct-acyclic-graphs-dags)